# RootReduce and Simplify for an algebraic expression

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

The American Invitational Mathematics Exam (AIME) 2006 asked contestants to reduce this expression:

$$\sqrt{104 \sqrt{6} + 468 \sqrt{10} + 144 \sqrt{15} + 2006}$$

The answer is $13 \sqrt{2} + 4 \sqrt{3} + 18 \sqrt{5}$, as can be verified by:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[104 Sqrt[6] + 468 Sqrt[10] + 144 Sqrt[15] + 2006] == 
  13 Sqrt[2] + 4 Sqrt[3] + 18 Sqrt[5]]
```

(* True *)

Alas, the direct approach for *Mathematica*-based such simplification of the expression in the problem doesn't work:

```
mySimple = RootReduce[Sqrt[104 Sqrt[6] + 468 Sqrt[10] + 144 Sqrt[15] + 2006]]
```

and

```
ToRadicals[mySimple]
```

I can make progress if I *know* (or guess) the algebraic extension:

```
term= Sqrt[104 Sqrt[6] + 468 Sqrt[10] + 144 Sqrt[15] + 2006];
FullSimplify@AlgebraicNumber[term, {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[5], Sqrt[15]}]
```

But what if I didn't know the extensions?

I've tried a number of methods, based on `FullSimplify`, `Expand`, and so on, but none work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already such a function on FunctionRepository called [RadicalDenest](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RadicalDenest).

```
term = Sqrt[104 Sqrt[6] + 468 Sqrt[10] + 144 Sqrt[15] + 2006];
ResourceFunction["RadicalDenest"][term]
```

> $13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}$

Another possible approach

```
poly = MinimalPolynomial[term, x]
sol = Solve[Factor[poly, Extension -> Sqrt@{2, 3, 5}] == 0, x]
Select[sol, PossibleZeroQ[(x /. #) - term] &]
```

> $2125355779600 - 13379972960 x^2 + 19011864 x^4 - 8024 x^6 + x^8$

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -13 \sqrt{2}-4 \sqrt{3}-18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to 13 \sqrt{2}-4 \sqrt{3}-18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to -13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}-18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to 13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}-18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to -13 \sqrt{2}-4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to 13 \sqrt{2}-4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to -13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}\right\},\left\{x\to 13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}\right\}\right\}$

> $\left\{\left\{x\to 13 \sqrt{2}+4 \sqrt{3}+18 \sqrt{5}\right\}\right\}$

Related Links:
[Radical Denest: an ancient difficult task in symbolic computation](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2120629),
[Heuristic package to denest radicals](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/980264)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I didn't know about `RadicalDenest`... a great help.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's my pleasure.